# How to track Twitter feed in real time?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter

I am going to make some service, but I am not sure about few things so please help if you could.
How to track in real time Twitter feed of some user, and make some action in my service when user put some tag in his feed? I don't want to ready solution, I have to know just what technologies and 3rd party libraries I have to learn?

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be using [Twitter's streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis) with a Json parser like [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

**EDIT**

Here is a sample code

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json");
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("....", "......");
webRequest.Timeout = -1;
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
while (true)
{
    var line = responseStream.ReadLine();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;

    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(line);

    if (obj.user != null)
        Console.WriteLine(obj.user.screen_name + ": " + obj.text);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to Twitter, http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/, supports Twitter streams. Here's an example:

```
        (from strm in twitterCtx.UserStream
         where strm.Type == UserStreamType.User
         select strm)
        .StreamingCallback(strm =>
        {
            if (strm.Status == TwitterErrorStatus.RequestProcessingException)
            {
                WebException wex = strm.Error as WebException;
                if (wex != null && wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(wex.Message + " You might want to reconnect.");
                }

                Console.WriteLine(strm.Error.ToString());
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(strm.Content + "\n");

            if (count++ >= 25)
            {
                strm.CloseStream();
            }
        })
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

That's a user stream, but you have similar support for filter, sample, site, and other streams.